# Unable to Ping Guest Ubuntu by Hostname

Tags: networking, vmware

A peculiar problem (per se). I am using VMWare Player on a Windows 10 Host. I installed a guest Ubuntu with the default NAT as network configuration. I set its hostname as `timeline`
I am unable to `ping timeline` from my Host Windows 10, it says

`Ping request could not find host timeline. Please check the name and try again.`

I have VMWare Workstation Pro on a different machine (a Lenovo Workstation), I am able to ping my guest VM by it's name!

```
C:\Users\Vikas>ping timeline

Pinging timeline.local [192.168.50.133] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.50.133: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.133: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.133: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.133: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

Notice the `.local` which is appended in this case. I am at my wit's end so as to why it's not working in the first scenario. I'm hosting a Wordpress in my guest VM so I was hoping the Host could automatically recognize or map the IP because that's what happening in the second case, I'm not giving any static host entry for the guest.
Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is expected in the first scenario because guest VM is behind a NAT. On second vm are you sure, it does have Same net setup and No other net interface as (bridged or host-only). Btw, `.local` is from Avahi mDNS deamon, are both VM's uses same Ubuntu image?

Comment: Thank you User.Dz for the welcome! Yes, I am positive - a simple default NAT. On my Lenovo P520, I created an Ubuntu from VMWare Workstation and exported it to OVF. Imported on my first machine (in the scenario) to see if the name resolution worked.. but no.

Comment: `192.168.50.133` is not your VM guest address, right?

Comment: Yes, and below is my host's config. VMNet8 is NAT..

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d581:4e97:f385:a832%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Comment: You need to set it into Bridged (not NAT neither Host). mDNS packets will not pass Router https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/72933/3965 also NAT will translate its source port.  Host Net settings also require a setup in Host Avahi deamon to set which net interface will active one so it will broadcast that corresponding IP address.